# InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

input_dim=8
layer1_dim=6

learning_rate=0.01

train_data=np.loadtxt("data.txt",dtype=float)
train_target=train_data[:,-1]
train_feature=train_data[:,0:-1]
test_data=np.loadtxt("data.txt",dtype=float)
test_target=test_data[:,-1]
test_feature=test_data[:,0:-1]


x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

w1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_dim,layer1_dim]))


b1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,layer1_dim]))


layer_1 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w1), b1))


loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(layer_1-y))

train_op =   tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

 init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)

    for i in range(10):
        print(session.run(train_op, feed_dict={x: train_feature, y: train_target}))
        print(layer_1)
        print(loss.eval())
```

Here is my error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
 [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Process finished with exit code 1

The data is just a normal matrix,which is 6x8 features and 6x1 targets.
The print of sess.run is None.
If I don't print the loss,there is no error but the None of sess.run.

Comment: What happens if you specify the dimensions in your placeholder declarations?

Comment: Cannot feed value of shape (6,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

Comment: Try and reshape the value from (6,) to (6,1)

Comment: @IanTimmis thanks a lot ,it works.

Comment: Good to hear. Could you upvote my comments?

Comment: I'd love to,but how?I am a novice in stackoverflow @IanTimmis

Comment: @IanTimmis I know it! I have not enough reputation for upvote u.If I have enough reputation,I will upvote u back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should double-check your inputs if they are really what you want. The following snippet works:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

input_dim = 8
layer1_dim = 6
learning_rate = 0.01

train_data = np.random.randn(6, 9).astype(np.float32)
train_target = np.expand_dims(train_data[:, -1], axis=-1)
train_feature = train_data[:, 0:-1]

assert train_feature.dtype == np.float32
assert train_target.dtype == np.float32
assert train_feature.shape == (6, 8)
assert train_target.shape == (6, 1)


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='plhdr_X')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='pldhr_Y')

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_dim, layer1_dim]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, layer1_dim]))

layer_1 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w1), b1))
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(layer_1 - y))

train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    for i in range(10):
        _, err = session.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={
                             x: train_feature, y: train_target})
        print err
```

You get more verbose information if you spend each placeholder a name.